# Getting substrings separated by spaces and tabs from a string in C

Tags: c, string

I need to write a programs which gets a command line from the user- the first word in the command line is the command itself and the rest are arguments for the command. The command and the arguments can be separated by many spaces and tabs the user wants. for example:
"Multiply    a         b"
"Multiply" is the command and "a" and "b" are names of 2 matrix.
The program needs to check if the first word is a valid command:

*if yes - it should check if the rest of the arguments are valid or if there are too many/less arguments for this specific command (the amount of the arguments differs between the commands).

*If the command is not valid or the number of the arguments is not good - it should print the same error.

My main issue is that I don't know how to separate between the command and the arguments if they are all in the same line together and I need to make a validation check for each command/argument in this line.
I tried do use a for loop for the first word but it doesn't work very good and I don't know what to do with the rest of the arguments.

```
fgets(command_line, sizeof(command_line), stdin);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(command_line); i++) {
            if (command_line[i] == ' ' || command_line[i] == '  ')
                position++;
        }
            while (c < strlen(command_line)) {
                command[c] = command_line[position + c];
                c++;
            }
            command[c] = '\0';
```

I'm very new to programming so I hope I was clear with my question and I will appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: How would a single character of input be equal to *two* spaces?

Comment: It's not two spaces, it suppose to be "tab" but now I guess it still counts as a space?

Comment: It's better to express that as `'\t'` so it's abundantly clear what you're doing.

Comment: I'm not sure what that `while` loop is supposed to do, but it looks like you should use `strncat()` instead. There's a lot of contextual code missing here.

Comment: This is a standard tokenization problem I'd write a function like `strtok()` but which is more lenient about tabs/spaces and having multiples of each. Then you can work with that data, pulling out one value after the next to work with. Try and use the original buffer whenever possible, avoid copies unless you need to dramatically restructure things. See how `strtok()` works, as an example.

Comment: The 'while' loop is not good enough since I need to get only one word, separated by spaces/table, each time so I can make validation tests for it and not the whole string as the while loop does right now.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the `strtok()`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't *write a function like `strtok()`*, I'd rather use `strtok()`, since it does what you need.

```
    #define MAX_ARGS 30  // or however many you need
    char *words[MAX_ARGS];
    int nargs = 0;
    for (char *tok, *str = command_line; tok = strtok(str, " \t\n"); str = NULL)
        if (nargs == MAX_ARGS) return 1;  // too many
        else words[nargs++] = tok;
    // now if nargs > 0, words[0] points to the command, words[1..nargs-1] the arguments
```

Note that the inclusion of `\n` in the set of delimiter characters serves to get rid of the line terminator left over by `fgets()`.